# P-value on statistical tests

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

If I have a p-value of 0.01 on a statistical test, does that mean the probability of my hypothesis being wrong is 1%?

If not, why not?

Comment: If null hypothesis is true, the probability of getting the data in the sample or more extreme data is the p-value. If p-value is small enough, you will not believe that null hypothesis is true. Pay attention: It is your null hypothesis.

Comment: That's not correct. It means that given your null hypothesis is true, the probability of getting a result as or more extreme as the one you got is only about 1%. Since this value is low it would make us skeptical that the null hypothesis is actually true.